# Event listener not working with firebase query

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, event-listener

I am trying to create an event listener to my firebase query script but it acts a little strange?!?

Here is my script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Firebase.Firestore;
 
public class TestDataHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    public GameObject testObject;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        fbEvent.AddListener(readyToGo);
        GetUserData("12345");
    }
 
    void readyToGo()
    {
        Debug.Log("Do Stuff");
        tetsObject.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log("Stuff Done");
    }
 
    UnityEvent fbEvent = new UnityEvent();
 
    public void GetUserData(string userId)
    {
 
        Query query = FirebaseDataManager.instance.users
            .WhereEqualTo("userId", userId
            );
 
        query.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWith(querySnapshotTask =>
        {
           
            if (querySnapshotTask.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.Log("No userdata is found");
            }
            else if (querySnapshotTask.Result.Documents.Count() < 1)
            {
                Debug.Log("No userdata is found");
            }
            else
            {
                DocumentSnapshot userData = querySnapshotTask.Result.Documents.FirstOrDefault();
                Dictionary<string, object> data = userData.ToDictionary();
 
                User tempUser = FirebaseSerializer.FBDataToObject(data) as User;
 
                Debug.Log("Userdata found: " + tempUser.firstName);
 
                fbEvent.Invoke();
            }
        });
    }
 
}
```

It kinda works, course the listener listens but I am not able to, in this example, deactivate an gameobject from the listener return function.

I get the "Do Stuff" log, but not the "Stuff Done" log and the GameObject is not deactivated?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name says `GetSnapshotAsync` is executed **async** ... meaning in a different [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task) (similar to thread). The `ContinueWith` is happening after this `Task` is finished **BUT** it is **NOT** guaranteed to be run on the main thread.

**Most of Unity's API may only be used within the Unity main thread.**

For Unity specific make sure to not use `ContinueWith` but rather the extension method [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension#class_firebase_1_1_extensions_1_1_task_extension_1af1fc309e7e9b9e9a3655b8b47cb06014) which additionally makes sure that callback is executed in the Untiy main thread so you can use the Unity API without threading issues.